# How to change text color using a button

Tags: javascript, button, text, colors

I'm modifying a page that we use at work. This page is a local html page that uses a js file for most of its functions. I've been able to troubleshoot some things and make it work in Chrome (before it only worked well in IE). But now I'm trying to change the background and color of text using some buttons or inputs.

This is purely for aesthetics and does not need to be addressed, I would just like to know what I'm doing wrong so I could make future projects better. The changing background using an input type of file is working perfectly. Now I'm just trying to change the color of text in the whole document (including elements, but I haven't got there yet in the code) by using the input type color. I've tried setting up an event listener, just like I used for the background image, but it's not working. I might be completely doing it wrong or something.

Here is the code for the html part...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> 
<title>
    CADI - Life
</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body background="https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple111/v4/11/4c/0e/114c0e6a-eb12-8158-a1c7-64632cfd6a3f/source/512x512bb.jpg" text="white" onclick="changeTabs()" onload="init()">
Choose your Background!<br>
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" />
<input type="color" id="textColor" name="favcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
```

And here is the JavaScript...

```
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL(){
   var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function(){
      document.body.style.background = "url(" + reader.result + ") black no-repeat center";        
   }
   if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}

document.getElementById('textColor').addEventListener('change', changeText, true);
function changeText(){
    var color = document.getElementById("textColor").value
    var looker = new ColorLooker();
    looker.onloadend = function(){
        document.body.style.text = "looker.result";
    }
    if(color){
        looker.color
    }else{
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the color to change when I choose a color on the color input. When I choose a color, nothing happens and the console tells me that ColorLooker is undefined.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the Java tag? They're actually completely unrelated languages, and this doesn't appear to have anything to do with that language.

Comment: That was my fault. I typed java and it was there. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

**Try replacing this **

As you need to change the text colour on the document you have to use body.color css format.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp

```
document.getElementById('textColor').addEventListener('change', changeText, true);
    function changeText(){
        var color = document.getElementById("textColor").value
         document.body.style.color = color;

    }
```

Comment: You are awesome! That works perfectly. I guess I was just trying to make it too complicated.

Comment: Hey @0kazaki101 , if you find it perfect solution can u please accept it as the best answer. Thank you